# im using scrollLeft in react but it's not setting it's value to element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm making a drag able slider on mouse move i'm taking a starting mouse position and subtracting it with current mouse position and setting it to state and adding it to element scroll Left but it's not working

```
onMouseMove = (e) => {
        if (!this.isDown) {
            return
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = e.pageX - this.slider.current.offsetLeft;
        var walk = this.startX - x;
        var z = this.scrollLeft - walk;
        console.log( this.slider.current.scrollLeft);
        this.setState({ left:  this.state.left + z })
        var slider = document.querySelector('.slider-container');
        // console.log(slider);

        slider.scrollLeft=this.state.left
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `this.setState` is not executed directly. It is queued to be processed by react. The callback can be used to determine when it has finished:

```
onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!this.isDown) {
        return
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.pageX - this.slider.current.offsetLeft;
    var walk = this.startX - x;
    var z = this.scrollLeft - walk;
    console.log( this.slider.current.scrollLeft);
    this.setState({ left:  this.state.left + z }, () => {
        var slider = document.querySelector('.slider-container');
        // console.log(slider);

        this.slider.scrollLeft=this.state.left
    })
}
```

Checkout the following example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  p = 0;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      left: 0
    };

    this.slider = React.createRef();
  }

  onMouseDown = e => {
    e.persist();
    this.isDown = true;

    this.startX = e.pageX - this.slider.current.offsetLeft;
    this.scrollLeft = this.slider.current.scrollLeft;
    this.slider.current.style.cursor = "grabbing";
    // console.log(
    //   e.pageX - this.slider.current.offsetLeft,
    //   this.slider.current.scrollLeft
    // );
  };
  onMouseLeave = () => {
    this.isDown = false;
  };
  onMouseUp = () => {
    this.isDown = false;
    this.slider.current.style.cursor = "pointer";
  };
  onMouseMove = e => {
    if (!this.isDown) {
      return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.pageX - this.slider.current.offsetLeft;
    var walk = (this.startX - x) / 20;
    var z = this.slider.current.scrollLeft - walk;

    this.setState({ left: this.state.left + z }, () => {
      this.slider.current.scrollLeft = this.state.left;
    });
  };
  goLeftPercent = () => {
    return {
      transform: `translatex(${this.p}px)`,
      transition: "0.3s"
    };
  };
  goLeft = () => {
    if (this.p < -970) {
      return;
    }
    this.p += -326;
    this.setState({ left: this.p, percent: true });
  };
  goRight = () => {
    if (this.p === 0) {
      return;
    }
    this.p += 326;
    this.setState({ left: this.p });
  };

  mouseMove = () => {
    if (this.state.left > 0) {
      this.setState({ left: 0 });
      return;
    } else if (this.state.left < -980) {
      this.setState({ left: -980 });
      return;
    }
    return {
      transform: `translatex(${this.state.left}px)`
    };
  };

  render() {
    const slides = [
      { src: "", name: "Livingroom1" },
      { src: "", name: "Livingroom2" }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="slider">
        <div className="slider-wrapper">
          <div
            onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
            style={this.state.percent ? this.goLeftPercent() : this.mouseMove()}
            onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
            onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
            onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove}
            ref={this.slider}
            className="slider-container test"
          >
            {slides.map(slide => (
              <div className="slide">
                <img src={slide.src} alt="" />
                <div className="overlay">
                  <h1>{slide.name}</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slider-arrows">
          <div onClick={this.goLeft} className="arrow-wrapper">
            {" "}
            Left
            <div className="arrow-left">
              <div className="arrow-top" /> <div className="arrow-bottom" />{" "}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div onClick={this.goRight} className="arrow-right">
            Right
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

interactive demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-murdock-8f766

Comment: Check updated example @NaveenKashyap If it still doesn't work, what part doesn't work?

Comment: i dont know how to use it in codepen but i posted my code there you check onMouseMove method and i'm trying to set scrollleft to slider-container thanks

Comment: Could you share the link? @NaveenKashyap

Comment: You forgot the create a ref in the constructor(`this.slider = React.createRef();`). Check the updated example in the answer @NaveenKashyap Check the demo version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-boyd-c5qsw

Comment: What part doesn't work? What should happen? You can drag with your mouse and the values get logged right? @NaveenKashyap

Comment: yeah and the container should  move too to scrollLeft im using translatex but it's choppy

Comment: the part doesn't work is it doesn't move to scrollLeft on dragging

Comment: Updated the answer, could you try it again? I also added a link to the live demo @NaveenKashyap

Comment: thanks it works but when ever i click second time it's going back to start

Comment: Click what part? @NaveenKashyap

Comment: when i drag second time  on the slider-container it goes back to 0 it should stay in  current position and goes forward from there

Comment: I don't understand what issue you are facing, the dragging keeps working on in each direction. If it is entirely on the left it can be dragged to the right by going to the edge and dragging @NaveenKashyap

Comment: i'm trying to slow it by dividing it by 5 try this u will know what im talking about   this.setState({ left: (((this.state.left || 0) + z)/5) }, () => {  });

Comment: no look the position of it it start from 0 when u drag second time

Comment: I fixed it by making the walk smaller: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-murdock-8f766 @NaveenKashyap

Comment: thanks i fixed it i was calculating from the first starting point but i have to set the starting point to previous every time i move my mouse

Comment: Great! Could you mark this answer as solution/upvote it so other can find it if they have a simular problem? @NaveenKashyap

Answer (score 2):

Just use 'Ref.current.scrollLeft += anyvalue;' or 'Ref.current.scrollLeft -= anyvalue;' (use '+' to scroll right and '-' to scroll left.)

this works for me in React:-

```
const handlePrevBtnClick = () => {
    Ref.current.scrollLeft -= 80; 
}

const handleNextBtnClick = () => {
    Ref.current.scrollLeft += 80; 
}
```